# Consolidate columns to create tract level census data in R or Excel

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, census

I have block level census data that contains an ID I use to merge it with block level shape files known as GEOID, this ID functions as a number of values who's meaning essentially gets geographically smaller

So you have country, state, county, tract, block in a number that looks like this "360050001000001" with the last 4 digits being the block

So I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image: Sample data] which continues on for dozens of more columns with granular race data and 37000+ rows

I have figured out a method to remove the last four digits of each GEOID so that they only represent the tract level in excel, no problem

The issue I have now is that I need all values of, say 36005000100 to be totaled up

So where I had "Total_Pop" of 5 different values for 36005000100, I need them all to be consolidated and summed up into one value. So the tract that would be 36005000100 might be the sum of 0 + 0 + 141 + 1344 + 367 + 1890, with this repeated based on the shared GEOID value. Each tract can contain anywhere from a few to dozens of blocks.

I have tried the consolidate function in excel but I can't seem to get it working right

I've looked into the merge and join functions for R but they primarily seem used for merging dataframes when I need to consolidate values

I'm trying to use the "aggregate" function in R as well and struggling with the appropriate syntax for my use

Comment: Using `dplyr` you could try `dat %>% group_by(GEOID) %>% summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE))`.

Comment: Perfect, that did it - I had completely forgotten about group_by. Thank you.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg